# How can I prove that: $55...5 = \frac{5}{9} (10^n -1)$

Tags: induction

How can I prove that:
$$55...5 = \frac{5}{9} (10^n -1)$$
while in the left side the number is $55...5$ (with $n$ occurrences of $5$).

I tried to do it with induction, but I don't know how to present the left side with $n$...

Comment: Recall that $(10^n-1)=(10-1)(10^{n-1}+10^{n-2}+\cdots+10+1)$.

Comment: Divide both sides by $5$, then clear denominators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
555 \ldots 5 &=5 \times (111 \ldots 1)\\
&=5 \big(1+10+100+\cdots 10^{n-1}\big)\\
&=5\left(\frac{10^n-1}{9} \right)
\end{align}

Geometric progression?

Answer (score 0):

Or $$55\ldots5 = 5\cdot 11\ldots1 = 5\cdot {99\ldots9\over 9} = 5\cdot {100\ldots0-1\over 9}= 5\cdot {10^n-1\over 9}$$

Comment: You may use `\ldots` for better spacing between dots.